# Удаление занятого процессом файла С#

Tags: c#

создаю чит для игры, но вот проблема, нужно подменить файлы, но разработчик додумался до того, чтобы заблокировать файл, но я бы был бы не собой, если бы использовал для этого Unlocker. Но вот беда, я сделал процесс который по нажатии кнопки должен удалять занятый файл, и подменять его заранее выбранным.
Был бы благодарен

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String filename = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "путь";
        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        var account = new NTAccount(identity.Name);
        FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(filename);
        fSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny));
        fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
        File.SetAccessControl(filename, fSecurity);
        File.Delete(filename);
        {
            string path = @"путь";           
            string newPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "путь";
            FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(path);
            if (fileInf.Exists)
            {
                fileInf.CopyTo(newPath, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Подменять файл в рантайме бессмысленно. Подменяй когда игра выключена. Допустим ты выгрузишь файл. Но для подгрузки игрой библиотеки заново игра должна быть перезапущена. То есть все равно прийдется выключать ее.

Comment: Игра не даёт такую возможность, там всё основано на том, чтобы заменить именно в нужный момент, по другому вылезет Uniti Crash

Comment: Тогда меняй данные в оперативке, а не в физическом файле. Как это обычно делают другие читы. Иначе юнити креш будет вылетать в любом случае - в какой момент файл не заменяй.